# GRASS7 plugin shell doesn't work

Tags: qgis-plugins, grass-gis

I am trying to run GRASS commands through the shell within the plugin. However, the shell from the GUI is bland and opening it up directly throws the error below.

```
Cleaning up temporary files...
Starting GRASS GIS...
ERROR: wxGUI requires wxPython. No module named 'wx'
You can still use GRASS GIS modules in the command line or in Python.
ERROR: Error in GUI startup. See messages above (if any) and if necessary, please report this error to the GRASS developers.
On systems with package manager, make sure you have the right GUI package, probably named grass-gui, installed.
```

Extra Info...
QGIS 3.10.3,
MacOS 10.14.6.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first error: Did you make sure that the wxPython package is installed? E.g. via `pip3 install wxpython` on the commandline. Installing this package is now part of the compilation process via homebrew for grass (see https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compiling_on_MacOSX_using_homebrew) and the package is needed for the GUI to work.

Regarding the second error: Is your default Python distribution anaconda? I've had some problems with installing GRASS on Mac (Catalina) via the command line. I got the same error when using anaconda python distribution. With a "plain" Python distribution I got another error, but it might work for you if you set your default Python distribution for example to the system python (/usr/local/bin).